# Scroll layout in webview android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am using web view in my application. web layout contains long layout so when i select on last edit text web view gets scroll but last edit text is not displaying focused because of it is hide from input soft keyboard . i want to show last edit text in visible view of web layout. any suggestion?

Xml

```
   <com.salesgyani.android.pos.activities.ScrollWebView 
            xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
            android:id="@+id/m_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:focusable="true" />
```

and JAVA

```
 public class ScrollWebView extends WebView {

   public ScrollWebView(Context context) {
          super(context);
   } 

   public ScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
   } 

   public ScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) { 
          super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
   }

   @Override 
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
         requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); 
         return super.onTouchEvent(event); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: i have changed in my webview xml layout : Added <com.salesgyani.android.pos.activities.ScrollWebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/m_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

Comment: public class ScrollWebView extends WebView {

     public ScrollWebView(Context context) {
  super(context);
 }

     public ScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
     }

     public ScrollWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
         super(context, attrs, defStyle);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
         requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }          
}

Comment: Edit your question and post all your layout xml. Also show a screenshot of what your layout looks like now and what you want it to look like. You need to give more information for us to help you.

Comment: Please don't post code as a comment as it is very hard to read.